# where is the storage location of the browser's HTTP cache? disk or memory

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser-cache, cache-control

where is the storage location of the browser's HTTP cache? disk or memory

I just want to know why some files come form disk cache and others from the memory cache, what's the mechanism behind of the HTTP cache? which cache has a higher priority?

It seems that scripts and stylesheets are stored in the disk, while images and fonts are stored in the memory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe is the file type?

Comment: When you say "the browser" you refer to Google Chrome?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## maybe solution

1. memory cache store images and fonts etc, little files
2. disk cache store js and css etc, big file

### cache control for disk cache

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

https://web.dev/http-cache/

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/get-started/httpcaching-6

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching