# Explicitly specify FileServer to use disk cache instead of memory cache with Go server with cache control header?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, cache-control

Currently, with Go's file server, I am serving files with Cache-control header. The browser is always storing these files in memory cache. How to specify it store it in disk cache instead?

Comment: Here's one possible explanation: this question has no relation to Go as it does not pose any problem with _progamming in_ Go (which is a programming language). The question is purely about possible ways of affecting the cache storage of a particular type of WWW client software. I would say the queston is 1) not properly tagged; 2) is anyway [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Although some browsers document how they make use of disk and memory to implement their cache, or use heuristics you may be able to exploit (e.g. [where is the storage location of the browser's HTTP cache? disk or memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824427/where-is-the-storage-location-of-the-browsers-http-cache-disk-or-memory)), there is no specification for how to control this remotely.

[RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) makes no mention of "disk" or "memory", and the cache is described in abstract terms as:

> Each cache entry consists of a cache key and one or more HTTP
> responses corresponding to prior requests that used the same key.

The [HTTP Cache Directive Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-cache-directives/http-cache-directives.xhtml) doesn't include any proposed or implemented extensions that would distinguish either.

Implement your own client with the caching behaviour you require, or accept that clients may or may not use disk or memory to cache any responses.